# Logical xhtml/css design

Tags: css, xhtml

My website uses supersized, so my background is never 'static'; eg: when you resize the browser window, the background image will resize itself too and so the top left corner of the website will have a slightly different background. Look at the following screenshots:

Current layout

[image: current]
http://cl.ly/0l2p3P3I432D1C1t0P3K/content

Current problem

[image: current problem]
http://cl.ly/2N1d032Z2G3Q2H04462V/content

Solution i have in mind will be in the next post, since i can't post more than 2 hyperlinks.

So, the thing is.. When i scroll down, the content (photographs) move up, overlapping the logo and flickr badge. There's an easy solution for this: overlay another absolute or fixed div with a solid colour with a z-index lower than the logo & flickr badge and higher than the photographs. So if you would scroll down, the pictures would dissapear below that fixed div. Yet, that is impossible since i don't have a fixed background, as i explained earlier (supersized).

Comment: Solution i have in mind: [link](http://cl.ly/1C0n431528124304240x/content)

Comment: Do you have to use a background image? What if you just stuck the image in a div tag?

Comment: How do you mean? The fullscreen scaling background image (supersized)?

Answer (score 0):

What you could do (but I guess its not exactly what you want) is use Jquery for the full background image, create a layer with a top margin and fixed height and width and use overflow to make this layer scrollable. Now if you scroll down the content will move only within this layer. Only problem: the scrollbar will be at the right side of the pictures.

Comment: You're right, that's not what i want but i appreciate your thought! Damn, this puzzle is harder than i thought..